# Get a specific file at a particular tag in GIT

Tags: git

I have a git repository called `foobar` which is very large (10 GB or so). I want automate the process of getting the contents of a particular file at a particular tag and process it. Right now, I do the following:

```
1. git init 
2. git fetch git://remote/foobar.git SOME_SPECIAL_TAG_03892
3. Get the file xyz.txt
```

The fetch operation takes up to 15 min since there are tens of thousands of tags, branches and histories in the repo. But the repository workspace has only 4 files (one of them being xyz.txt).

What is the best way to get the contents of `xyz.txt` at tag `SOME_SPECIAL_TAG_03892`? Is it possible to do `git remote-ls` to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can just use

```
git show SOME_SPECIAL_TAG_03892:xyz.txt
```

An example:

```
git show tags/v1.0.5:README.md
```

This will print the contents of README.md how it looked like in v1.0.5 to stdout, hence you can do with it as you please, for instance redirect it to a file etc.

See [the docs (`<rev>:<path>`)](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememREADMEememmasterREADMEem) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try a shallow fetch.

```
git fetch --depth=1 git://remote/foobar.git SOME_SPECIAL_TAG_03892
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following steps.Hope these command will help you

```
    git show object
    git show $REV:$FILE
    git show somebranch:from/the/root/xyz.txt
    git show HEAD^^^:test/abc.py
```

The command takes the usual style of revision, meaning you can use any of the following:

1. branch name
2. `HEAD` + x number of `^` characters
3. The SHA1 hash of a given revision
4. The first few (maybe 10) characters of a given SHA1 hash